# Could not find a command named "keytool" Flutter

Tags: java, android, flutter, keystore, keytool

Im a new developer who try to publish my app to playstore.

```
  keytool -genkey -v -keystore c:\Users\USER_NAME\upload-keystore.jks -storetype JKS -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000 -alias upload
```

To create a key store i just past this command prompt (windows 10)pc.

and shows this.

```
[  +44 ms] Could not find a command named "keytool".
```

*I already installed java by the way*

And I just ran `flutter doctor` it shows

```
  Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.5.3, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19042.1348], locale en-GB)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 31.0.0)
[X] Chrome - develop for the web (Cannot find Chrome executable at .\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe)
    ! Cannot find Chrome. Try setting CHROME_EXECUTABLE to a Chrome executable.
[√] Android Studio (version 2020.3)
[√] VS Code (version 1.63.1)
[√] Connected device (1 available)

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

Then I check so many tutorial to solve something like edit environment path" but sadly still not worked.

So can anyone kindly help me please

Comment: `keytool` is just a part of the Java SDK. If you haven't already got Java installed, download it https://www.java.com/download/ie_manual.jsp

Comment: I already downloaded sorry for saying late

Answer (score 0):

`keytool` is a program that is distributed with the Java Development Kit. If you don't have this kit, you can visit Oracle.com and download it for free. The program is located in the kits' `bin` folder. On my system the path to the folder containing `keytool` is `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-15.0.2\bin`

Your system may be different.

Comment: sorry i installed it already sorry for saying that late